# GTK - Python Window Symbolic Icon Color Problem

Tags: python, svg, icons, gtk, gtk3

I have a `GTK3` GUI called by a simple Python 3 code. Icon is located in the `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/actions/` directory. My current theme color is dark and icons look white. When I switch to white system theme GUI icons turn into black. But in my code icon looks as black instead of white when dark theme is activated.

It works when I choose the icon name (`icon-symbolic`) from Glade program and save the UI file. Icon file is a simple black square .svg file (drawn in Inkscape).

What is the solution for that?

```
OS: Debian-like Linux, Python 3, GTK 3.24
```

Simple Python code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file('test.ui')
window1 = builder.get_object('window1')
button1 = builder.get_object('button1')

class Signals:
    def on_window1_destroy(self, widget):
        Gtk.main_quit()

builder.connect_signals(Signals())

window1.set_icon_name("icon-symbolic")
window1.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Simple UI file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.38.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <property name="default-width">300</property>
    <property name="default-height">300</property>
    <child>
      <!-- n-columns=1 n-rows=1 -->
      <object class="GtkGrid">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can-focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Button 1</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives-default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left-attach">0</property>
            <property name="top-attach">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: You said "it works" when you define the image in the UI file: do you mean that the icon colors are correct or incorrect?

Comment: Icon colors are correct. In other words, icon colors change to opposite color of the GUI (dark icons on white system GUI, white icons on dark system GUI).

Comment: Why not just define the icons in the UI file?

Comment: This is a simple example. In my code icons are defined in the UI file but sometimes icons are defined as they are defined in this simple example. Because these icons change in some situations. They are not same always.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I should have thought of that :-).

Comment: Try `#bebebe` instead of `#000000`? https://askubuntu.com/questions/148955/why-do-the-gnome-symbolic-icons-appear-darker-in-a-running-application

Comment: @nelfin, I have already tried it but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Do you have problem with system toolbar (where launched apps are) or with icons inside your widgets? If latter, how do you set them?

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev, I have problem with application windows and treeview rows (cellrendererpixbuf). It works on other widgets with svg icons when icons are set from Glade. But sometimes I have to set them during runtime and there is the color problem. It looks like color changeable feature of the  svg images is lost when pixbuf is used for icons and color changeable feature is not supported on window titlebars even if pixbuf is not used. I have tried several methods but none of them worked when pixbuf is used.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem only partially: I've added a `GtkImage` to the grid, it renders ok and dynamically changes when I change theme. However, system toolbar icon is always black. I'd suggest taking a look at `GtkIconTheme`, especially `gtk_icon_theme_load_icon()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution for automatically changing icon color on the window title bar. I have used `Gtk.HeaderBar` instead of default window title bar and added an `Gtk.Image` (its name is `image_headerbar`) to the left of the headerbar. Finally I have set image icon by using the following code and it worked:

`image_headerbar.set_from_icon_name("icon-symbolic", -1)`

Icon color changes to dark/white automatically when system theme changes to white/dark.

I have tried several methods for dynamically changing icon color on the window title bar. But none of them worked if `Gtk.HeaderBar` is not used.

But window title bar height is a bit bigger than default window title bars when `Gtk.HeaderBar` is used (tested on XFCE desktop environment).